# c# dotnet project fails to run: assembly file not found

Tags: c#, .net, linux, .net-assembly

I am trying to get a dotnet project running under Debian 9.9 (stretch).

I cloned the repository from here:
https://github.com/Montesuma80/3cx-web-API

After installing the dotnet packages (3.1 SDK from the Microsoft repository), building failed, as a dependency listed was not found. I edited the the .csproj file to match the actual location of the dll file on my system in the HintPath-Tag (its a phone system installed locally):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="3cxpscomcpp2">
      <HintPath>/usr/lib/3cxpbx/3cxpscomcpp2.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>false</Private>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

After this change, the code compiled successfully.

But when running the compiled code, I get the following error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly '3cxpscomcpp2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53c4927ce4749cb4'. The system cannot find the file specified.

File name: '3cxpscomcpp2, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=53c4927ce4749cb4'
   at WebAPI.Program.Bootstrap(String[] args)
   at WebAPI.Program.Main(String[] args) in /root/webapi/3cx-web-API/Program.cs:line 418
```

The file does exist in the path specified. I tried deleting the bin and obj folders an starting over while copying the dll to the project dir, same result. Building works fine but running fails to find the assembly. I checked the version of dll file on my system, 2.0.0.0 is the correct version.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Remove `<Private>False</Private>` - when it's set - dll is not copied to `bin` folder

Comment: Likq quercus mentioned, ensure that the file is actually in your output (bin/debug) directory, and if that doesn't work try adding `<SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>` to the reference (just to test for me). In visual studio ` <Private>false</Private>` will show up as  'copy local = false' so the file is likely not being copied.

Comment: @Quercus thanks, your hint solved it. Can you post it as an answer, so I can give you proper credit? ;)

Comment: can you please tell me where from I get 3cxpscomcpp2.dl ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove

```xml
<Private>False</Private>
```

from `Reference`
When it's set - dll is not copied to bin folder